# Unable to redirect to calling page after exporting the cfunction output to excel using cfcontent tag

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I’m trying to export the contents of function output to a excel using the click of a button. I have created a action page for the button, which calls the export to excel page using cfheader and cfcontent tag. Exporting the excel using these tags works fine but after the cfcontent tag I have created a form and redirecting it back to the calling page. The code after the cfcontent tag are not executing and page is not redirecting. how should i redirect it after the cfcontent tag? Please help me on the issue.

This is the code I'm using for exporting to excel.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="strExcelData">
    <cfoutput>#fn_retrieveData()#</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=Audit_#DateFormat(Now(),'ddmmyyyy')#.xls"/>
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.msexcel" variable="#ToBinary( ToBase64( strExcelData.Trim() ) )#"/>

<form name=frm_AuditTrail method=POST action=tchk_AuditTrailSearch.cfm>
<cfoutput>
    <input type='hidden' name='txt_searchstr1' id='txt_searchstr1' value='#FORM.txt_searchstr1#' />
    <input type='hidden' name='txt_searchstr2' id='txt_searchstr2' value='#FORM.txt_searchstr2#' />
</cfoutput>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function()
    {
        alert("windows.onload is redirecting to review data page NOW");
        document.frm_AuditTrail.submit();
        return;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have any output after a `<cfcontent>` tag; it is ignored. Only the contents of the `<cfcontent>` tag are sent back to the browser.

[From the docs for cfcontent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c82.html):

```
variable  Optional  Name of a ColdFusion binary variable whose contents can be 
                    displayed by the browser, such as the contents of a chart 
                    generated by the cfchart tag or a PDF or Excel file retrieved 
                    by a cffile action="readBinary" tag. When you use this 
                    attribute, any other output on the current CFML page is 
                    ignored; only the contents of the file are sent to the client.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. then what is the solution to redirect it to the calling page?

Comment: You don't need to redirect to the calling page. The `<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" ...` tag will prompt the user to open the file in Excel, etc.  The calling page will still be in the browser.

Comment: The calling page is in the browser but it is blank!!

Comment: You need to have whatever output you want sent to the browser before you send the Excel file. So send the HTML output to the browser with a button/link/whatever to download the Excel file. That button/link/whatever action will call the ColdFusion page that has the `<cfcontent>` tag.

Comment: Sorry Miguel... i'm not getting your point. Currently i have 1page.cfm where i have a button to export the excel. On click of the excel button it will go to 2nd Page. In second page i have mentioned the cfcontent tag and it is loading the excel file. After loading the excel file, browser address bar still shows 1stPage address ut it is blank.

Comment: So is your button submitting a form to 2nd page? Try giving your form a `target="_blank"` attribute.

Comment: Yes.. the button was submitting to second page. When i use target="-blank" in form , second page opened in new window and downloaded the excel. But still the 1st page displays blank after the button click.

Comment: Something else must be changing the 1st page then. That is not normal behavior. With the `target="_blank"` attribute you are telling the browser to submit in a new tab/page leaving the current page alone. Do you have javascript firing on/after the form submission that is modifying the current document?

Comment: No i have not used any javascript firing after the form submit. This is the code i'm using for that...<script type="text/javascript">
function fn_AuditExport()
{
 var strhtml="";
 
 var searchstr1=document.getElementById("tmp_searchstr1").value;
  
 strhtml += "<form name='frm_submitAction' method='POST' action='tchk_ExportToExcelAuditTrail.cfm?' target='_blank'>"
  strhtml += "</form>"
 location.reload();
  document.write(strhtml)
  frm_submitAction.submit() 
    
}
</script>

Comment: Why are you doing this `location.reload();`?  That may be the culprit.

Comment: Earlier i was not using location.reload();, i thought it could refresh the page so added it. Without that statement also its not working :( :(

Comment: Get rid of the `document.write(strhtml)` as well. You don't need to do anything but submit the form. By design the original page will still be in the browser.